If $n$ is an even and $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$ and also of the equation $x^{2n} + p^nx^n + q^n = 0$ ...

If $n$ is an even and $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$ and also of the equation $x^{2n} + p^nx^n + q^n = 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{(1+x)^n}{1+x^n}$ where $\alpha^n + \beta^n ≠ 0, p ≠ 0$, find the value of $f(\frac{\alpha}{\beta})$.

I ve seen various interpretations for its solution though here's my approach, please tell why it fails:
Given, $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^2 + px + q = 0 \implies \alpha + \beta = -p$.
Also, $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^{2n} + p^nx^n + q^n = 0$
$ \implies \alpha^{2n} - \beta^{2n} + p^n(\alpha^n - \beta^n) = 0$
$ \implies (\alpha^n + \beta^n)(\alpha^n - \beta^n) + p^n(\alpha^n - \beta^n) = 0$
$ \implies (\alpha^n - \beta^n)(\alpha^n + \beta^n + p^n) = 0$
So, we've two cases now, the second case  easily gives the desired answer for the question but the first case troubles also it's not sure that $\alpha^n - \beta^n$ is non-zero.

The case $\alpha^n-\beta^n=0$ implies $(p^n)^2-4q^n=0\implies (4q)^n-4q^n=0\implies \color{red}{n=1}$, which makes both equations coincide. But $n$ is even. So, $\alpha^n\neq\beta^n$. For any even $n$, you have to consider the second case.
So, for even $n$:
$$f\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) =\frac{\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^n}{1+\frac{\alpha^n}{\beta^n}}= \frac{(\alpha +\beta)^n}{\alpha^n +\beta^n}=\frac{(-p)^n}{-p^n}=\frac{p^n}{-p^{n}}=-1.$$
